# Cloudwatch: Monitoring SNS based on MessageAttribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have several backend services which publish to a single SNS topic. The specific publishing service is designated as a field in `MessageAttributes`. Conversely, I have a single consumer subscribed to all messages from this topic.

I'd like to monitor this SNS topic in Cloudwatch to determine if the number of messages being published per backend service is as expected. Is there a way for me to partition this information in cloudwatch based on a value in message attributes?

**Note:** I am aware that Cloudwatch can monitor number of messages based on [SNS Filter Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html). My concern is that I have a single consumer – would creating additional filter policies be expensive/wasteful?

Comment: The filter policy metrics did not used to show how many messages are being filtered out per policy or never used to. Although not using Cloudwatch I have used Firehose + Athena to query the messages that have been sent via SNS, the MessageAttribute in question could then be grouped to compare the number of messages. Alternatively you could use a Lambda that processes the messages on the topic and generates custom metrics into Cloudwatch based on the Attribute you are interested in making it possible to use in dashboards and alarms.

Comment: Helpful @lprentice – convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter policy metrics sadly do not support the granularity you are looking for at a policy level. In order to keep the metrics within Cloudwatch you could use a Lambda that processes the messages on the topic and generates custom metrics into Cloudwatch based on the Attribute you are interested in making it possible to use in dashboards and alarms.

At a high-level the flow would be SNS -> Lambda -> Cloudwatch. Rather than using the CloudWatch API to push the metrics you could make use of the Cloudwatch embedded metric format.

Depending on your setup you could instead add metrics into the backend services that are making the PublishMessage calls. At least this way no new components would be needed to capture the metrics.

Comment: Any estimate on cost considerations for implementing a lambda to consume all messages? Also, as far as metrics on publishing volume >> a concern is to measure the diff between messages thought to be published and messages actually published. (If any are dropped)

Comment: Will of course depend on volume but if using EMF then no external calls need to be made so would expect it to take a couple of ms to process each message given its parsing the message in memory then logging the metric to stdout essentially. By dropped is that due to a filter policy of failure to deliver? Adding the metrics into the producing service may be more time consuming depending on the setup. If you dont already have a way of capturing, displaying and alerting on metrics from the backend services producing the messages, using the lambda could be more simple overall.

Comment: Theres no new chargers from SNS for sending to Lambda but Lambda costs apply. Lets say for example your sending 1 million messages, it takes 25ms to process each message and logs in aggregate are 5GB each month it would cost under $5 to process and store the metrics https://calculator.aws/#/estimate?id=5384e58448c2a7be805f1901994630b560544549

Comment: Helpful! Can you update your answer to include these added points?